# Unity: Are running Coroutines destroyed upon loading new scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerable, scene, coroutine

If you have a coroutine running in a script attached to an object in a given scene, when that scene ends, does the coroutine get terminated/destroyed? ...even if the coroutine contains e.g. an endless While loop?

---

For instance, if I have the following coroutine attached to an object in my scene:

```
IEnumerator SampleCoroutine()
{
    while (true) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

...when a new scene is loaded, assuming no script attached to the object contains "`DontDestroyOnLoad(...)`", will the coroutine still execute in the newly loaded scene?

Reason for asking: I need to know whether I need to keep a list of all active Coroutines, so that I can end them after every scene change. I don't want performance to degrade as more scenes are used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer:

Yes, they will be terminated as `Coroutine`s run depending on `MonoBehaviour` they were started on. No `MonoBehaviour` == No `Coroutine`.

Comment: So just to clarify, they WILL be terminated when the object they were called on is destroyed?

Comment: @BenHayward It's the MonoBehaviour that calls `StartCoroutine` that determines when it is stopped. For example. If MonoBehaviour `A` calls `StartCoroutine` using MonoBehaviour `B`'s `IEnumerator` method, then the coroutine will only stop being called when MonoBehviour **`A`** is destroyed.

Comment: @BenHayward exactly like gjttt1 is saying. I edited the answer cause my asnwer started with 'no' but should with 'yes'.

Comment: I'll add one important detail: While the coroutine might might be stopped when the scene loads, it's still better to express the Coroutine to stop (especially big complex ones) prior to changing scene so that the Coroutine's memory can properly be destroyed by the Garbage Collector (GC). Otherwise, either the blocks will all be chunked in the GC at once (making load more unstable if heavy) or there is a chance that the block will hang in limbo (unused, but not completely destroyed) for a while.

Comment: The GC only destroys memory blocks that are properly tagged as to be destroyed. (The "DontDestroyOnLoad" for example expressly tells its to not destroy the relevant blocks even if they are unused.) When you close a scene and a coroutine is still active, sometimes, it takes a while for its relevant memory blocks to be tagged to be destroyed, making the tasks hang over onto the next scene (which can drop the performances).